# Symbols not displayed in Emulator, but displays in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've added a `Button` in my `layout.xml` as shown below:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sell_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="@string/sell"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In my `strings.xml`, I've defined the string variable `sell` as shown below:

```
    <string name="sell">sell ></string>
```

In the layout's graphical view, the button text is displayed as `sell >`.

But in emulator, the symbol `>` is not displayed. That is, I am getting only `sell`.

I've tried changing the value of `sell` as `sell \>` and `sell \\>`. But nothing gets displayed properly.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using,

```
<string name="sell">sell ></string>
```

Try like below:

```
<string name="sell">sell &gt;</string>
```

When using symbols, it is better to use `HTML` entities, like `&gt;`.

Reference: [List of HTML Character Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).